# Google Apps Marketplace SDK configuration disappeared

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I had a working configuration for the Google Apps Marketplace SDK and I went to make change a few days later only to get the following screen
[image]

I already have web clients configured......

Please help

Comment: I think this is more of a specific support, you can file a [new bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191597&template=823910) which a specialize group can help. This may be a problem due to a bug in the service itself.

Comment: Thanks, I've submitted a ticket

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue.

Comment: @PoonamMalve after a long back and forth with the support guys, it just re-appeared. Try going to the IAM section and just change someone's restriction there, doesn't matter to what. changing it will trigger re-fetching of all the data it this is what fixed it for me.